# DatePicker not working correctly. how to set it up?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker

I took the info from https://reactdatepicker.com/
but it doesn't look right:
[DatePicker which I requested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daidU.jpg)

[DatePicker at home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wbhyy.jpg)

Can you tell me how to write it correctly to get a calendar like from the site reactdatepicker?

my code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { observer } from "mobx-react-lite";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import { Row } from "react-bootstrap";

const Budget = observer(() => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());

return (
<Row>
      <DatePicker
        selected={startDate}
        onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
        dateFormat="MM/yyyy"
        showMonthYearPicker
      />
</Row>
);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should import css.

```
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
```